# Tengo un problema a la hora de logearme, no me esta comparando bien la contraseña encryptada

Tags: typescript

Este es el login

```
   export const loginUser = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    try {
        const user = await findUserByEmail(email);

        console.log('Contraseña proporcionada:', password);
        console.log('Contraseña almacenada:', user.password);

        const passwordMatch: boolean = await comparePassword(password, user.password);

        console.log('Resultado de la comparación:', passwordMatch);

        if (!passwordMatch) {
            throw new Error('Contraseña incorrecta');
        }

        const token = generateToken(user.idusers.toString());

        return { user, token };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error al iniciar sesión:', error);
        throw new Error('Error al iniciar sesión');
    }
}
```

Y este es el error que me da

```
Contraseña proporcionada: prueba123
Contraseña almacenada: $2b$04$X8O/G7H1aZXRshba7VSCdu1c.Uqg8oQC8ZWz0T6DtCslnD54dPdYK
Resultado de la comparación: false
Error al iniciar sesión: Error: Contraseña incorrecta
    at C:\Users\Rodri\Desktop\ProyectoEcommerce\src\services\userServices.ts:57:19
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Rodri\Desktop\ProyectoEcommerce\src\services\userServices.ts:5:58)
```

---

Gracias por las respuestas! añado mas información

```
    import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

export const hashPassword = async (password: string) =>{
const saltRounds = 4
return await bcrypt.hash (password, saltRounds)
}
               

  export const comparePassword = async (password: string, hashedPassword: string) =>{
return await bcrypt.compare (password, hashedPassword)
 }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! typescript? o node?? de paso, parece que te falto encriptar la contra proporcionada por el usuario

Comment: Si cifras tu contraseña con bcrypt es mas facil hacer la comparacion porque no necesitas cifrar de nuevo la contraseña en el login, ademas no proporcionaste como haces la comparacion, esa funcion no me dice nada mas que recibe 2 parametros y regresa un boleano, asi como dice el comentario de arriba tienes que selecionar bein la etiqueta, esto es NodeJS, ademas no te podriamos dar solucion si no sabemos que hace la funcion. Editala y vemos, saludos!